# Можно ли удалённо подключиться по ADB к устройству без подключения к одной сети Wi-fi?

Tags: android, adb

Можно ли как-нибудь взаимодействовать с устройством через Android ADB удалённо, то есть без локального подключения к USB и без подключения к одной сети WiFi. То есть, чтобы пользователь скачал приложение, выдал разрешение на откладку и это устройство смогло подключиться к серверу и уже можно было с ним удалённо работать на уровне разработчика.
Искал решение в интернете, пришёл к выводу, что возможно только через USB или с root-правами, но в любом случае только подключаясь к одной сети Wi-Fi. Может кто знает какой-нибудь секрет)

Comment: в чем проблема использовать одну сеть?

Comment: @eri, наверное в том, что юзер находится в другом городе, стране, континенте.

Comment: Секретов не знаю, но может дам пищу для размышления. Андроид умеет делать отладку по TCP IP - это любое сетевое подключение, не обязательно WiFi. Но активируется эта опция через USB подключение и отключается при перезагрузке устройства, так что без ПК или root не обойтись. Через внешний IP Андроид скорее всего к себе не пустит, но если организовать VPN подключение - то думаю должно получиться.

Comment: @woesss и тут нет проблемы загнать их в одну сеть

Comment: @eri, ну так пишите ответ, раз для вас это не проблема